# Set total equal to zero when computes the sum of given numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie of python and I'm trying to practice some exercises, however I'm stuck with the line "total = 0" in this code. Actually I don't really understand why this value is initialized to 0.
Could anyone please explain it for me ?

```
def main():
    print("This program allows you to total up some numbers")
    print()

    n = int(input("How many numbers do you have? "))
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        total = total + num

    print()
    print("The sum of the numbers is:", total)

main()
```

Comment: How would `total = total + num` work in the first iteration if `total` would have not been initialized with `0`?

Comment: FWIW, that entire loop and initialization can be replaced with `sum(float(input("Enter a number: ")) for _ in range(n))`

Comment: The loop gives you the opportunity to catch `ValueError`s raised by individual calls to `float`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that line and you see you will get an error:

> NameError: name 'total' is not defined

This is because both `total` and `num` must be initialised before you can use them in `total = total + num`

You initialise it before the `for` loop otherwise it would be reset to 0 each time.